# Proving an algebraic problem categorically

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, category-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove that $\text{Ab}(\mathop{\Large {*}}_\alpha G_\alpha) \simeq \bigoplus_\alpha \text{Ab}(G_\alpha)$, where $\text{Ab}(G)=G/[G,G]$. I attempted to prove it categorically and am wondering if the following justification is correct.

Define the covariant functor $\text{Ab}:\text{Grp}\to \text{AbGrp}$ by sending objects $G\in \text{Ob}(\text{Grp})$ to $G/[G,G]\in \text{Ob}(\text{Ab})$ and morphisms $f \in \text{Hom}(G,H)$ to $f' \in \text{Hom}(\text{Ab}(G),\text{Ab}(H))$ by $f'([g]_G)=[f(g)]_H$. The well-definedness of $f'$ can be easily checked.

Since the free product is the coproduct in the category $\text{Grp}$, it follows that for all groups $H$ and morphisms $f_\alpha:G_\alpha\to H$, there exists a unique $f:\mathop{\Large *}_\alpha G_\alpha\to H$ such that $f \circ \iota_\alpha=f_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

Now, suppose $H$ is abelian. Then, Ab$(H)\simeq H$. Now, take a family of morphisms $\{g_\alpha:\text{Ab}(G_\alpha)\to H\}$, and define $f_\alpha:G_\alpha \to H$ by $f_\alpha(k)=g_\alpha([k]_G)$ for all $k \in G_\alpha$. It can easily be checked that $\text{Ab}(f_\alpha)=g_\alpha$. Using this family of functions $\{f_\alpha\}$ and abelian group $H$, one can take the above coproduct setup and apply the Ab functor to everything. This yields the following:

For all abelian groups $H$ and morphisms $\{g_\alpha:\text{Ab}(G_\alpha)\to H\}$, there exists a unique function $\text{Ab}(f):\text{Ab}(\mathop{\Large *}_\alpha G_\alpha)\to H$ such that $\text{Ab}(f)\circ \text{Ab}(\iota_\alpha)=g_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. However, this is exactly the definition of the coproduct of $\text{Ab}(G_\alpha)$ in the category AbGrp, and since the direct sum is the unique coproduct in the category AbGrp, it follows that $\text{Ab}(\mathop{\Large *}_\alpha G_\alpha)\simeq \bigoplus_\alpha \text{Ab}(G_\alpha)$.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: You should use the fact that the functor $\mathrm{Ab}\colon\mathsf{Group}\to\mathsf{AbGrp}$ and the inclusion functor $\iota\colon\mathsf{AbGrp}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{Group}$ are adjoints: $\mathsf{Group}(G,\iota(A)) \cong \mathsf{AbGrp}(\mathrm{Ab}(G),A)$. That is essentially what you are re-doing, but using the machinery of adjoint functors gives it directly, since a Hom set from a coproduct is naturally isomorphic to the product of the Hom sets.

Comment: As per the `solution-verification` tag: which single step are you unsure about, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That argument is correct.

Note that (more or less by definition) the $\mathrm{Ab}$-functor is left-adjoint to the inclusion functor from abelian groups to groups. From that perspective, the property you're interested in is actually an instance of the more general fact that left adjoint functors preserve colimits (and therefore, in particular, coproducts), which can be proved in full generality by completely analogous reasoning.

Comment: Also, the argument by moboDawn resembles the argument that colimits in a reflective subcategory of a cocomplete category exist and are computed by applying the localizer (the left adjoint) to the colimit in the supercategory. Reflective subcategories are also a nice direction to generalize this statement into.